# How to create message with Slack Block Kit, Bolt and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, slack, slack-block-kit

I created the following BLOCK but cannot figure out how to use it within a /Command. It shows fine when used within the ack({...}) but does nothing when I use say({...}). The only other way is the client.dialog with type: modal but that is not what I want.

I simple need to know how to respond using my JSON block kit code. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
    "attachments": [
        {
            "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "context",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": user_id + ", this was your question",
                            "emoji": True
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                                "text": question,
                                "emoji": True
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "context",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Here's what I found",
                            "emoji": True
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": answer
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                                "text": "Info",
                                "emoji": True
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "context",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Author:* " + author
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "context",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Book:* " + booktitle
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "context",
                    "elements": [
                        {
                            "type": "mrkdwn",
                            "text": "*Page:* " + str(page_num)
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": content
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "divider"
                },
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "Was this helpful?"
                    },
                    "accessory": {
                        "type": "static_select",
                        "placeholder": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "please select an answer from the drop-down",
                            "emoji": True
                        },
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                            "text": "*This was spot on*",
                                            "emoji": True
                                },
                                "value": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                            "text": "*This was somewhat helpful*",
                                            "emoji": True
                                },
                                "value": "0"
                            },
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                            "text": "*This was not helpful*",
                                            "emoji": True
                                },
                                "value": "-1"
                            }
                        ],
                        "action_id": "static_select-action"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

EDIT
could this work?

```
  client.chat_postMessage(
    channel=event['channel'],
    blocks=[
        {...})
```

EDIT

```
@app.command("/q")
def q_command(client, event, ack, command):
ack("Gotcha! Let me take a look...")
user_id = event.get("user")
#...
client.chat_postMessage(
    channel=event['channel'],
    blocks=[
        { ... }])
```

Comment: Can you add more context? Do you need to post a reply in response to a slash command, but need to format it in the given block kit manner?

Comment: Or do you want to open a Modal form ?

Comment: NO model form, just want to post. My guess is I can use this:   
client.chat_postMessage(
        channel=event['channel'],
        blocks=[
            {

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned will work.

Although, if you just want to respond to the same channel/dm where the command was invoked, 
 you should use **`response_url`** received in the **event payload**.

 https://api.slack.com/interactivity/handling#message_responses

```
let res = await axios.post(rsp_url, {
      blocks: blocks
    });
```

**For further reading :**
You can also check the following documentation.

 SDK : https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/webhook/index.html#response-url

 Message Types: https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/web/index.html#messaging

Comment: Not working! I have spent an entire day by know. This is really frustrating. Can anyone maybe help with a full example?